# Unable to debug javascript in Visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I tried to debug my javascript but it doesn't fires the breakpoint.

I am using IE8 and VS2010.

On trying to add

**debugger;**

an error occurs like;

**An unhandled exception (script breakpoint) occured in iexplorer.exe
Possible debuggers:**

I found that Tools-->Debugging-->Just In Time-->script is unchecked.

I checked it and saved....It remains unchecked....

I repaired my visual studio still issue continues...

The issue occures after i had installed VS2012

Comment: have you checked in google chrome or mozila??

Comment: yes i have checked...but no use

Comment: Please check this.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-explorer-wont-workan-unhandled-exception/37b78d56-0f38-43ed-8e87-fdae72197d6c

Comment: If you have [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe) installed, it could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but I found out why this happened to me. I had

```
debugger;
```

scattered throughout my javascript file because both IE and Chrome would not hit my breakpoints.

When using IE and hitting F12 for Developer Tools, the code breaks on the debugger lines but the Windows pop-up did not open. Hitting "Continue" in the debugger window executed the code normally.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I believe its too late to reply.

But deploy your solution in Visual Studio in RELEASE MODE and NOT IN DEBUG MODE.

This solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197255/enable-the-javascript-debugger-in-the-page-inspector) so answer, seems you are not doing all the steps required

Comment: I tried it but i haven't found any WebBrowserServer.exe.. I tried with IE, chrome and firefox...The breakpoint never fires.

Comment: Try attaching the processes named "w3wp.exe"

Comment: I am running from my localhost...I didn't find w3wp.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I renamed default.html to index.html and lost script debugging.

Go to the project properties web tab.  Make sure 'Start Action' is set to 'Specific Page' and your start page is selected in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools => Options = > Debugging => Just-In-Time and uncheck Script to sto