# Visual Studio 2012 JavaScript Debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, javascript-debugger

All of a sudden, launching a web site in debug mode using Visual Studio 2012 no longer attaches the JavaScript debugger.  I have to manually attach to the new Internet Explorer process that launched, and I have to do this everytime that I launch the debugger.  I have searched the web all day and have tried numerous things to fix this, and nothing seems to work.

I have tried the following:
 1. Resetting my Visual Studio settings
 2. Repairing Visual Studio
 3. Reinstalling Visual Studio
 4. Running the following command:
regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the IE setting: Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > In Browsing category > "Disable script debugging" check boxes (both)? Are they unchecked?  You can also check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197255/enable-the-javascript-debugger-in-the-page-inspector

Comment: Yes, both checkboxes are unchecked.  I can manually attach to the IE process, but I have to do that every single time.  It used to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue.  For reference for others, here are the exact steps I did:

1. Open Control Panel > Turn Windows features on or off
2. Uncheck Internet Explorer 10
3. Click Ok
4. Restart
5. After restart open Control Panel > Turn Windows features on or off
6. Check Internet Explorer 10
7. Click Ok
8. Restart

At this point my JavaScript debugging worked again.