# Visual Studio 2012 javascript debugger stopped working

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012, javascript-debugger

Visual Studio 2012 stopped debugging javascript files. 
Javascript debugging was working fine few days ago but all of a sudden it stopped working. 
I tried using script debugging in IE but I am not feeling comfortable with that.
Anyone has a proven solution for this issue?

My system details are given below,

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
IE: Version 9
VS: 2012 Premium

Thanks,
Vim

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [How to debug (only) JavaScript in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568245/how-to-javascriptonly-debug-on-visual-studio)

and this : [Enable the javascript debugger in the Page Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197255/enable-the-javascript-debugger-in-the-page-inspector)

or this : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/08/30/use-visual-studio-2012-to-debug-javascript-code-outside-the-running-project.aspx

You have to track back your steps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try the steps mentioned in the above URLs and reply back the status.

Comment: I am currently following your first suggestion: how to Javascript(only) debug on Visual Studio?. And, I feel inconvenient withPage Inspector. Is it possible to re-enable javascript debugger in my Visual Studio 2012?